# Centering Navbar Content when it is not fixed with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm trying to center the "content" on navbar. When it is "navbar-fixed-top" the UL menus are centered. However, since I don't want to fix the menu to the top I remove that class but now menus are not centered.
It is floating to the left side. It should be aligned to the margins of the container. 
Similar as http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html but I don't want it to be fixed to the top.

[image]

This is the code

```
        <div class="navbar ">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container" >
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your question correctly, so you want to fix your navbar content within a, lets say, `940px` container? The width of the `.container` div?

Comment: I don't want to fix actually. Instead of fixing I want to use it after header for example as shown in the picture. What I want is the content floats to left. It should be aligned to center. like margin:0 auto; width:940px; ... . But it doesn't work

Comment: you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5TpJH/1/show/

Answer (score 6):

Use `navbar-static-top`.

Check out the latest bootstrap version if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Couldn't figure out what was wrong but adding that class works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

This used to be the default behaviour, at least it worked in 2.0.1, but it seems there has been some changes in the latest versions so that the navbar content is no longer centered when the navbar is not fixed.

The workaround seems to be to add the following to your CSS:

```
.navbar-inner > .container { width:940px; }
```

Comment: Using the mixing is probably a better way to go: @include core-span($gridColumns);